# Highlighting text based on its match with another string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to highlight text based on whether it's matched with a string recieved from a database or not. To show the problem, here's an example. 
Given this text:

```
<div class='text'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

And this text:

```
<div id='matchingHighlight'>
Lorem ipsum <!-- Highlight this text within <div id='text'></div> !-->
</div>
```

How would I highlight the text within `.text` that matches with the text from `#matchingHighlight` (Lorem ipsum)?

Comment: if it is plain text, than it is a simple string replacement

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To 'highlight' the keyword / phrases, you will need to wrap it around any inline element. I'm suggesting you use `<span>` tag.

The following logic will replace the text with the same text wrapped inside a `span` tag with a class of `.highlight`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $text = $('.text');
    var textToHighlight = $('#matchingHighlight').text().trim();
    var textCurrent = $text.html().trim();
    var isTextExists = textCurrent.indexOf(textToHighlight) > -1;

    if(isTextExists) {
        textCurrent = textCurrent.replace(textToHighlight, "<span class='highlight'>" + textToHighlight + "</span>");
        $text.html(textCurrent);
    }
});
```

You can then style it using css, for example

```
.highlight {
    background: yellow;
}
```

https://pastebin.com/vaB3wa96